# Spring mvc character encoding error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Having a dispachetServlet configured as:

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters()
{
    return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), characterEncodingFilter() };
}

private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

private CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter()
{
    final CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding( CHARACTER_ENCODING );
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding( true );
    return characterEncodingFilter;
}
```

And a meta on html as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Why when I submit a form with text characters: ç, ñ... I'm getting on controller wrong characters like: Ã§aÃ§a

How can I fix it?

**UPDATED**

I'm using thymeleaf instead of jsp and I'm  getting parameters:

```
@RequestMapping( value = REGISTRATION, method = POST )
public String processRegistration( @ModelAttribute("userForm") User user, Model model )
{
    if( userService.existEmail(user)  )
    {
        model.addAttribute("duplicatedMail", true);
        return REGISTRATION_VIEW;
    }
    if( userService.existUsername(user)  )
    {
        model.addAttribute("duplicatedUsername", true);
        return REGISTRATION_VIEW;
    }
    userService.register( user );
    return REGISTRATION_SUCCESS_VIEW;
}
```

Comment: Do you use JSP? If so, do you have something like `<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` in the JSP?

Comment: Do you submit a GET or a POST? How do you get the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter(), new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
```

**Note:** You need to add CharacterEncodingFilter before HiddenHttpMethodFilter since latter calls ServletRequest.getParameter method internally.

Hope this helps.